# Add Screen Snip shortcut to notifications area in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, snipping-tool

I have two PCs with Windows 10 Pro 1809 installed on both machines.

On one of them in the notifications area it shows a shortcut for the snipping tool like so: 
[image]

The other machine does not have that shortcut. How can I add it? I've been looking around everywhere and I cannot find a single article that talks about this shortcut.

Comment: https://winaero.com/blog/take-screenshot-screen-snip-windows-10/

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia they're asking how to add the shortcut, not how to take a screenshot.

Comment: @tanner that's also mentioned in the link, found with a simple Google search.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia it doesn't say how to add it to the notification area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the notification area and right-click in it. Click "Edit", "Add", and then you should have the option to add "Screen snip".

Comment: right-clicking the notification area does not work for me, no menu pops up

Comment: Is it installed on your PC? https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MZ95KL8MR0L